Ubuntu won’t wake up after shutting laptop
I’m new to Ubuntu but I’ll try to be descriptive. I open my laptop today to find this error on a black screen.
[86527.305460] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Port E/TC#2: timeout waiting for PHY ready.
I have opened it and closed it only to find that it adds a new line with the same error. I also can’t access the boot manager because the power button isn’t responding. I am using 24.04 and on a Lenovo slim pro 9i 16”. Like I said I am new to Ubuntu and do not know all the functions of it yet. What can I do to get my laptop working again?

Of course you have removed the battery and unplugged the machine and plugged it back in again to make it restart. If it still does not restart you have a hardware issue. Time for the repair shop.
